# Spring MVC Hibernate use dynamic SQL Tables

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am creating an Spring Hibernate project where I need to dynamically create tables. The problem is that, with static/ predefined tables, we  used to create POJO Entity class for Hibernate SQL table where I already have the table names & their columns.

In current case, I don't know the SQL tables names at development time since they will be created dynamically. So, what is the solution of this problem?

I was searching for the same, I got [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels) link. I still didn't understand the process, i.e. where to create the `hibernate-mapping` file, what is the name of the file. In the mapping file also, class name(entity-name) is defined in the example show in the link i.e. `Customer`. How it become dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

You can leave table name blank (just don't add @Table annotation) and add [Custom Naming Strategy](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/implementing-a-custom-namingstrategy-with-hibernate/) to resolve the table name for the class